# Sort a list or characters using a customer sort order of characters in python

Tags: python

```
   L1=['1', '3', '4']
   L2=['2', '3', '5']
  custom_sort_order  =  ['2', '5', '3', '1', '4']
```

I tried to use sorted funtion however could not figure it out. Result should look like this

```
  L1_result=['3', '1', '4']
  L2_result=['2', '5', '3']
```

Comment: Please show the code that uses the `sorted()` function. You can do this using `key` and `index()`.

Comment: result= sorted(L1,lambda custom_sort_order  :custom_sort_order  [1])
       print(result)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that code. Also show what the result was when you ran it.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you want something like this.

```py
L1=['1', '3', '4']
L2=['2', '3', '5']
sort_order  =  ['2', '5', '3', '1', '4']
# sort lists based on location in var "sort_order"
L1.sort(key=sort_order.index) # pass in index as function
L2.sort(key=lambda x: sort_order.index(x)) # use lambda as function

print(L1, L2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your attempt:

```
result= sorted(L1,lambda custom_sort_order :custom_sort_order [1])
```

Here you are declaring a new variable named `custom_sort_order` that has nothing to do with your list of the same name. The argument to the `lambda` is each element of the list. So you are just sorting by the first letter of each string:

```
result = sorted(L1, key=lambda x : custom_sort_order.index(x))
```

Note that I also expliclty name the argument `key` which is the standard way of doing this.

Since you are just passing `x` to another function, you can use that function more directly instead:

```
result = sorted(L1, key=custom_sort_order.index)
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was a little confused about that. It works

Comment: @AbhishekArora I edited my answer to explain how to fix you attempt to arrive at the correct solution. I hope this helps you understand it better.